# Ginger Beer Plant and lemon in one container or not?

Tags: ginger-beer

When making Ginger Beer using Ginger Beer Plant, should I use lemon or not? Some guides just have a step where they add lemon (into the same container as the GBP). Then again there are statements like

> Many times it can be irritating

from http://www.yemoos.com/gingerbeerguide.html

Does lemon **harm or benefit** the plant? Could it be that a small amount of lemon is beneficial while a larger amount can be damaging? Does it make a difference whether I use just the juice, or lemon slices, with or without skin?

Answer (score 2):

Giving the plant a little citric acid isn't going to harm the yeast, too much may harm both bacteria and the yeast but pushing he pH out of the optimal range, but juice of 1 lemon isn't going to cause any harm, and likely the addition of extra nutrients will help.